# Why doesn't line fitting seem to work in polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polar-coordinates

I have 2 points, $(r_1, \theta_1)$ and $(r_2, \theta_2)$. They are plotted and I'm trying to find a curve in the form of $r=\theta\beta_1+\beta_2$ to connect both of them. This is basically performing a line fitting and we can simply solve for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ in the following equation without doing fancy stuff such as projecting the solution back to the solution space:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_1 & 1 \\
\theta_2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1 \\
r_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution I get is

$$
\begin{align}
\beta_1 &= \frac{r_1-r_2}{\theta_1-\theta_2} \\
\beta_2 &= \frac{\theta_1r_2-\theta_2r_1}{\theta_1-\theta_2}
\end{align}
$$

Everything seems fine if the points are both in right quadrants. If one of them is at the left quadrants, the curve seems off.

[image]

This is [the tool](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tanxrxb1va) I'm using to plot the graph.

Comment: Always be careful with the domain of inverse trigonometric functions. It does not properly convert your cartesian coordinates of $A$ and $B$ to polar when they have a negative $x$ coordinate.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish - Oh you are right! By fixing the $arctan$ function I indeed got the expected result now. Thanks.